# Cakephp Twitch.Tv API Load Times

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I am working with the following code:

```
public function getUser($name) {
        $return = array();
        $file = array();
        $httpSocket = new HttpSocket();
        $url = $this->baseUrl . $name . $this->apiKey;
        $temp = $httpSocket->get($url);
        $file = $temp->body;
        $file = explode(',', $file);
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($file as $info) {
            $info = str_replace("{", "", $info);
            $info = str_replace("}", "", $info);
            $info = str_replace('"', "", $info);
            $info = str_replace("[", "", $info);
            $info = str_replace("]", "", $info);
            $temp = explode(':', $info, 2);

            if ($temp[0] == 'stream') {
                $temp[1] = str_replace("game:", "", $temp[1]);
                if ($temp[1] == 'StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty') {
                    $temp[1] = 'starcraft-II';
                }
                $return[$i]['game'] = $temp[1];
            } elseif ($temp[0] == 'teams') {
                $temp[1] = str_replace("name:", "", $temp[1]);
                if ($temp[1] != '') {
                    $return[$i]['teams'] = $temp[1];
                } else {
                    $return[$i]['teams'] = null;
                }
            } else {
                if (isset($temp[1])) {
                    $return[$i][$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
                }
            }
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

I was wondering if there is anything I can do to reduce the load times of this script. I am pulling a json file from TwitchTV for the record. The functionality works great just on page refreshes/loads there is a noticeable 2-3 second delay in the page rendering. As always any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the response from the API is json? Why are you parsing the response manually instead of using json_decode()? Use json_decode() and take a look at what it will generate. You can drop 90% of your code.

Also I would cache the API response, depending on your needs, for a few minutes up to a few hours. Read the Caching chapter of the book http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html The page should immediately load on a refresh because it does not need to make another API call then.